# Mongoose update multiple subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update one subdocument `addresses` (works) and then update many subdocuments except the previous one. Basically every time an `address` change `is_preferred` to true, it must update the previous address that `is_preferred` was `true` to `false` (i'm trying to update everyone except the address that changed to true).

User document

```js
_id: ObjectId("5b996f0fd5fbf511709f668f");
addresses: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ba33e0991cd7a3bb85dab7e");
    is_preferred:true
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ba3e9337310c637207b44cb");
    is_preferred:false
  }
]
```

Here is my solution:

```js
// model
User = mongoose.model('user', new Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    addresses: [
        {
            _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
            is_preferred: { type: Boolean, required: true }
        }
    ],
}, { collection: 'user' }););

// route
router.put('/updateAddress/:addressId', auth, user.updateAddress);

// user.js
exports.updateAddress = wrap(async(req, res, next) => {
    // update one object address `is_preferred` to true and return an array 'addresses' containing it
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { addresses: { $elemMatch: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.addressId) } } }, { 'addresses.$': req.body },
        { projection: { 
            addresses: { 
                $elemMatch: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.addressId) }
            }
        }, new: true }).lean();
    if (user) {
        // updated object `is_preferred` changed to true, so another objects must be false
        if (user.addresses[0].is_preferred) {
            // doesnt work
            await User.update({ _id: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.addressId) }, is_preferred: true },
                { $set: { addresses: { is_preferred: false } } }, { multi: true });
        }
        res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Saved.', new_object: user.addresses[0]});
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'Error.'});
    }
});
```

I'm able to update the `user` subdocument `addresses` `is_preferred` to `true`. However updating another `addresses` `is_preferred` to `false` isn't working. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend for a scenario like yours to utilize the mongoose middleware `pre` or `post` schema hooks. The idea is that instead of dealing with this in your controller you would take care of it in your schema via that middleware.

The only inconvenience is that the `pre` and `post` hooks do not fire on `findOneAndUpdate` and you would need to do first `find` then `update`.

So you would do something like this for the `post` hook:

```
User.post('save', doc => {
  // You can update all the rest of the addresses here.
});
```

Also for your update to work you need to do something like this:

```
User.update(
   { "addresses._id": { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.addressId) }}, 
   { $set: { 'addresses.0.is_preferred': false }}, 
   { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got updated working with `$elemMatch` like this: `{ addresses: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.addressId) } } } }`